# How do I do fill down with formula in reverse order in Google Sheet

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When I fill down with formula starting with, say, =A9, it will auto fill with =A10, =A11, A=12, in incrementing order.  But I want it to fill down in reverse order as =A8, =A7, =A6, how do I do that?  In Excel, I can select 2 cells, =A10 and =A9, Excel will know to fill in reverse order.

Comment: No simple way of doing that that I know of...  I suppose some form of `INDIRECT` arrayformula could do this.

Comment: I have found a page with [solution](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-flip-a-column-in-google-sheets/) that works.  Here is the formula.

=SORT(A9:A15,ROW(A9:A15)*N(A9:A15<>""),0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) function within the formula

```
=SEQUENCE(7,1,11,-1)
```

or even as

```
=SEQUENCE(7,1,11,-1)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

If you need to **reverse the order of already existing values in cells** you can use:

```
=SORT(A1:A9,ROW(A1:A9),0)
```

or even the following to exclude empty rows

```
=SORT(A1:A9,ROW(A1:A9)*N(A1:A9<>""),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=SORT(ROW(A:A), 1, 0)
```

[image]

---

or if you want from 10 to 5

```
=SORT(ROW(A5:A10), 1, 0)
```

---

or to flip the column values:

```
=SORT(A9:A15, ROW(A9:A15)*N(A9:A15<>""), 0)
```

Comment: Is this correct?  ROW gives me the number of rows in the range.

Comment: I think you meant =SORT(A5:A10, 1, 0), it sorts.  It is close, I want reverse order and not sorted.

Comment: @Tom it was not specified... can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: I have found a page with [solution](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-flip-a-column-in-google-sheets/) that works.  Here is the formula, also using sort.

=SORT(A9:A15,ROW(A9:A15)*N(A9:A15<>""),0)